# Spring <http> namespace seems to cause all non-role based pages to be allowed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to configure spring MVC to not authenticate any pages that have no authentication (enable the use of `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` as explicitly required for all pages).

But I get this message in the debug logs:

```
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Public object - authentication not attempted
```

The `FilterSecurityInterceptor` is added by the  namespace. And I *think* I need to `setRejectPublicInvocations` on the filter to disable this.

But I don't see any way to do this through the http namespace. Do I have to abandon using the http namespace entirely just to accomplish this?

Comment: It would be useful to see yout applicationContext-security.xml

Answer (score -1):

In my case I basically did this.

and it's working for anon users.

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginform.*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/topic/addtopic**"
        access="hasAnyRole('USER_ROLE','ADMIN_ROLE','OPER_ROLE')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**"
        access="hasAnyRole('USER_ROLE','ADMIN_ROLE','OPER_ROLE')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN_ROLE')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/cadastro.*" filters="none" />
    <form-login login-page="/loginform.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginform.html?error=invalido" />
</http>
```

Comment: The problem is, if you have a page /foobar.html that you didn't explicitly grant a role too it will be served as a "public" page/object. I don't want that. I want to ensure that ALL pages are EXPLICITLY defined in terms of permissions (e.g. the page must be given ROLE_ANONYMOUS permissions or it's denied).